# ¿Cómo recorrer una TABLE que tiene paginación?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy en una encrucijada, no puedo recorrer una tabla inicializada con datatable por que tiene paginación y al recorrerla solamente me trae lo visible y no lo que está en las otras paginas.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacer un *foreach* que recorra toda la tabla, saltarse la paginación y capturar toda la data de esta?

Código HTML:

```
<table id="tabla_pagos-mn" class="datatables display table table-striped small td_expanded_5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Rut Empresa</th>
            <th>Nombre Empresa</th>
            <th>Nombre Archivo</th>
            <th>Folio</th>
            <th>Monto Total</th>
            <th>Fecha Pago</th>
            <th>Fecha Recepci&oacute;n</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Origen</th>
            <th>Cantidad Registros</th>
            <th>Numero Contrato</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_grid">  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Llenado con Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.Action(" URLTEST ", " Home "))",
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    serverSide: true,
    success: function (rst) {

        for (var i in arraylist.Data) {
            $("#tbody_grid").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].CODIGO + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].FECHA + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].FECHA_RECEPCION_a + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].FECHA_RECEPCION_b + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].DESC_ESTADO + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + arraylist.Data[i].PROCEDENCIA + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");

        }
    })
};
```

Comment: agrega  el ejemplo, tambien estas usando la libreria datatables necesitamos mas informacion

Comment: ¿De qué forma estás llenando tu `Datatable` con Ajax o con data local? ¿Para qué quieres recorrer todas las filas?. Deberías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código de cómo lo llenas como la forma que estás haciendo de obtener las filas.

Comment: @Davlio Necesito recorrer esta table porque voy a convertir su data en string[] para generar un Excel.

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando utilizas [File export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export)?, ahí tiene la opción de exportar a Excel.

Comment: @Davlio Existen variadas formas de hacer un excel, pero en estricto rigor no es por lo que los he convocado. la urgencia mía es poder recorrer la tabla por completo evitando que la paginacion me corte la captura de la data.

Comment: @ManuKeteimporta acabo de darme cuenta que me equivoqué al entenderte, creí que usabas [DataTables](https://datatables.net). Viendo tu código no veo como estás manejando la paginación, me das a entender que estás trayendo toda la información.

Comment: @Davlio la <Tabla > esta llamando al datatables.min.js para inicializar todas sus herramientas de paginacion, ordenamiento, búsqueda, etc.

Comment: Lo tendras que hacer por medio de nodos, [checa esto](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetNodes)

Comment: Si tienes acceso a la url que genera el contenido... por qué no simplemente lees la respuesta de esa página y generas el contenido que necesitas?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a esta interrogante fue utilizar los controles de despliegue del datatables.
cuando se inicializa el datatables crea un  combobox con opciones de 10 , 25, 100, ,all. estos valores representan a la cantidad de data que tu quieres mostrar por cada pagina de la tabla.
para Solucionar mi problema de quere obtener toda la data que se encontraba en las demás paginas tuve que ejecutar un "trigger jquery". y decirle al datatable muestra toda la información y luego vuelve a mostrar 10 Rows en la tabla, de esta manera.

```
 $("#dt-button").click(function () {
    $('#tabla_pagos-mn_length select').val('-1').trigger("change"); // ACÁ LE DIGO: QUIERO QUE MUESTRES TODA LA DATA.   
    $("#PagoMN_Grid").each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());           //ACÁ LE DIGO RECORRE TODA LA TABLA.
    });
    $('#tabla_pagos-mn_length select').val('10').trigger("change");// ACÁ LE DIGO VUELVE A MOSTRAR 10 ROWS.
});
```

de esta forma pude capturar todos los valores de la tabla con paginacions.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el **iterator** del mismo datatable para recorrer la tabla completa. La variable node corresponde al **$(tr)** en turno

```
$('#example').DataTable().rows().iterator('row', function(context, index){
    var node = $(this.row(index).node()); 
    //node.context is element of tr generated by jQuery DataTables.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Contenido HTML**

```
<div>
    <button id ="btnCagar">Cargar</button>
</div>
    <table id="tabla_persona" class="datatables display table table-striped small td_expanded_5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </table>
<div>
    <p id ="valor"></p>     
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
```

**Contenido Javascript y Ajax**

```
    //Datos para llenar la tabla 
    var datos = [
    {
    "id":"01",
    "nombres":"Pablo",
    "apellidos":"Perez"
    },
    {
    "id":"02",
    "nombres":"Carmen",
    "apellidos":"Salinas"
    },
    {
    "id":"03",
    "nombres":"Jorge",
    "apellidos":"Baez"
    }
    ];

    //Variable para crear la tabla
    var d = '<tr>'+
    '<th>ID</th>'+
    '<th>Nombres</th>'+
    '<th>Apellidos</th>'+
    '</tr>';

    //Llenamos la tabla con los valores del json (datos)
    $("#btnCagar").click(function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
     d+= '<tr>'+
     '<td>'+datos[i].id+'</td>'+
     '<td>'+datos[i].nombres+'</td>'+
     '<td>'+datos[i].apellidos+'</td>'+
     '</tr>';
     }
     $("#tabla_persona").append(d);

     recorrerTabla();
    });

    //Funcion para recorrer la tabla que creamos
    function recorrerTabla()
    {
    var arrayPersonasID = new Array();
    var contador =0;
    var personasId;
    $('#tabla_persona' + ' tr').each(function(index){
    $(this).children("td").each(function(index2){
    switch(index2){
    case 0:
    personasId = $(this).text();
    //Tambien se puede asignar directamente a cualquier elemento del DOM
    $('#valor').text($(this).text());
    //Puedes almacenarlos en memoria para utilizarlos en otro punto
    arrayPersonasID[contador] = personasId;
    contador++;
    break;
    case 1:
    //En este caso son los nombres
    break;
    case 2:
    //En este caso son los apellidos
    break;
    }
    });
    });
    }
```

Esta es la forma en que se puede recorrer una Tabla. La logica se encuentra en el metodo *recorrerTabla*, es el que realiza las iteraciones por cada fila y celda.

Answer (score 0):

MUcho más simple que las anteriores respuestas, si usas la librería Datatable de este sitio https://datatables.net/ podrás acceder a todos tus datos mediante la función data

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
console.log("Cantidad de elementos: "+table.data().length);

//Si deseas recorrerlo
table.data().each(function(d){
   //Aqui haces lo que deseas con cada elemento
})
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que esta querindo decir es toma la informacion de una consulta

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table  table-striped dataTable" id="dataTable1" aria-describedby="dataTable1_info" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID  </th>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>Aciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>ID  </th>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>Aciones</th>
      </tr>
        </tfoot>
    <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" id="showdata">
    </tbody>
  </

table>
<script>
$.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Roles/showAllRoles',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          var html = '';
          var i;
        var t = $('#dataTable1').DataTable();
        t.clear();
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){   
        var counter = 1;
        t.row.add( [
            data[i].id,
            data[i].nombre,       

            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; '+
            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'
        ] ).draw( true );
          }
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('No se pudo carga los datos ');
        }
      });
```